# between and overlaps to be used interchangeably

Tags: postgresql

What is the difference between "BETWEEN" AND "OVERLAPS" in postgresql?

can you provide an example? is it possible to have a NULL value in the overlaps syntax
(NULL, x) OVERLAPS (?, ?).

Answer (score 1):

With a, b, c integers, `a between b and c` means just what it means in plain english:

```
b <= a and a <= c
```

With a, b, c, d integers, `[a,b] overlaps [c,d]` means they've elements in common:

```
not(b <= c) and not(d <= a)
```

(Mind bounds when dealing with overlaps.)

The null value means infinity when dealing with range types.

---

Examples:

```
denis=# select int4range(-1, 0), int4range(0, 1);
 int4range | int4range 
-----------+-----------
 [-1,0)    | [0,1)
(1 row)

denis=# select int4range(null, 0), int4range(0, null);
 int4range | int4range 
-----------+-----------
 (,0)      | [0,)
(1 row)

denis=# select int4range(null, 0) && int4range(0, null) as test;
 test 
------
 f
(1 row)

denis=# select int4range(null, 1) && int4range(0, null) as test;
 test 
------
 t
(1 row)
```